# Add custom filed on register in megnto 2

Tags: magento

Hi i want to add custom filed in magento 2 on register i,e company name etc  so how can I achieve this i did,t find any documentation regarding this
I follow this  https://mage2.pro/t/topic/1331   but is there any simple documentation  there 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to make a custom attribute if you are using magento enterprise go to

> Customers > Attributes > Manage Attributes

and create a new attribute.

If you are using magento comunity than follow this answer
[Make custom attribute programmatically](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/5906/38088)